# how to retrieve a document with some parameters excluded in the nested array in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the attached document structure. I need to retrieve the document with only some parameter.

For example 
I need  the data to be like this.

```
{
  "_id": "57f36d71fb1ef61bd84f866b",
  "testMaxScore": 235,
  "testMaxTime": 60,
  "inviteId": "57f0a97d11594560c02a8f43",
  "testName": "Sr. Interactive Developer l1",
  "sectionList": [
    {
      "sectionName": "Java MCQ",
      "sectionInfo": "Some info",
      "questionList": [
        {
          "_id": "57ea3d003f2ec2cbbe98bbb9",
          "question": ""
        },
          {
          "_id": "57ea3d003f2ec2cbbe98bbb9",
          "question": ""
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

[image]

How can i acheve this ?
I am using mongoose

Can anyone help me on this

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible through the aggregation framework. Consider running an aggregation operation that has a single pipeline with the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator to project just the fields you want.

In the above example, you would run it as

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "testMaxScore": 1,
            "testMaxTime": 1,
            "inviteId": 1,
            "testName": 1
            "sectionList.sectionName" : 1,
            "sectionList.sectionInfo" : 1,
            "sectionList.questionList._id": 1,
            "sectionList.questionList.question": 1
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

or using the **`find()`** method:

```
Model.find(
    { },
    {
        "testMaxScore": 1,
        "testMaxTime": 1,
        "inviteId": 1,
        "testName": 1
        "sectionList.sectionName" : 1,
        "sectionList.sectionInfo" : 1,
        "sectionList.questionList._id": 1,
        "sectionList.questionList.question": 1
    }
).exec(function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following find expression:

```
yourSchema.find({}).select('testName inviteId sectionList.sectionName'); // and so on
```